Is my laptop even capable of manual fan control? If not how do I get it to work automatically?
Recently switched from windows to Ubuntu on my Dell G7 7590. My fans don't seem to be working all that well.They do run but incredibly slow. No fan control software ever worked on Windows except AWCC, I tried HWiNFO and FanSpeed[I am not trying to see the temps but rather want to control the fan speed]. I am using Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS [Intel® Core™ i7-9750H × 12] [16GB RAM] [RTX2060 6GB].
I also remember that fan speeds used to work well automatically even without AWCC installed after fresh install of windows. There is no option in the BIOS for me to control the fans. I can only see logs of when the fans start/stop.
NOT using dual-boot. I am quite new to linux but can follow basic instructions.
I have installed i8kutils but I am not able to control anything as the GUI will not open.
I used the watch sensors cammand and can see ceratin temps from different sensors but nothing about the fans themselves, no rpms. Same when I run sensors after installing lm-sensors. Worst case I might try using dual-boot windows just to run AWCC but I would really prefer not to. Thanks

It is not an ideal fix but I installed windows on my additional drive [alongside ubuntu which was installed first] and installed all updates and drivers from there. I don't which one exactly did it but it is probably the power or thermal management I downloaded from the dell driver website directly and installed. I booted back into ubuntu and formatted the windows drive and the fans are working well enough. No manual control yet but I can play games peacefully. I would still prefer manual control if at all possible but this works for now.
